# Return data from reader.readAsArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, reader

I have the following code. I am trying to return the uploadData array back to the hello variable. However it is returning as a blank array.
The console log prints out the correct array of data, like this:
{name: 'bob'}, but after the reader.readAsArrayBuffer line, it becomes blank. Does anyone know why?

```
Hello = validateSpreadsheet(file, rows)

validateSpreadsheet = function (fileUpload, templateRows) {
  let uploadData = [];
  for (const file of fileUpload.files) {
    const fileExtension = file.name.split(".").pop();
    let valid = false;
    if (fileExtension === "csv") {
      valid = true;
    }
    if (!valid) {
      throw "Unsupported file type, file must be 'of type .csv";
    }
    const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = async (e) => {
  const data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);

  const workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
    type: "array",
    cellDates: true,
    dateNF: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  });
  if (workbook.SheetNames.length === 0) {
    console.error("No sheets");
  }
  for (const sheetName of workbook.SheetNames) {
    const rows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName], {
      defval: null,
    });

    for (let row of rows) {
      uploadData.push(row);
    }
  }
  console.log(uploadData);
};
   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    return uploadData;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uploadData` isn't updated until your `reader.onload` function is called (it is called asynchronously). So, to get around this, you can pass a callback function to `validateSpreadsheet` that receives the correct `uploadData`.

```js
validateSpreadsheet(file, rows, function (uploadData) {
  // do something with the data here
  console.log(uploadData);
});

validateSpreadsheet = function (fileUpload, templateRows, callback) {
  let uploadData = [];
  for (const file of fileUpload.files) {
    const fileExtension = file.name.split(".").pop();
    let valid = false;
    if (fileExtension === "csv") {
      valid = true;
    }
    if (!valid) {
      throw "Unsupported file type, file must be 'of type .csv";
    }
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = async (e) => {
      const data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);

      const workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: "array",
        cellDates: true,
        dateNF: "dd/mm/yyyy",
      });
      if (workbook.SheetNames.length === 0) {
        console.error("No sheets");
      }
      for (const sheetName of workbook.SheetNames) {
        const rows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName], {
          defval: null,
        });

        for (let row of rows) {
          uploadData.push(row);
        }
      }
      console.log(uploadData);
      callback(uploadData);        // the correct `uploadData` will be passed to your callback here
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    return uploadData;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: How do I assign a this.variable to the uploadData? Like this: validateSpreadsheet(fileUpload, this.templateRows, function (uploadData) {
      this.bob = uploadData;
    }); I get this error - Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'bob')

Comment: @Coder123 if you read your error closely, it is saying that `this` is undefined and therefore has no properties.

Comment: Thanks, but i just want to set a variable this.data, which is currently equal to a blank array, equal to the uploadData. Do you know how to do that? How do I define this?